# How to make addEventListener affect multiple divs

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am new to code, so please don't be too harsh on me. I am using this code to create a button that would store and load edited data from localStorage, and make divs with the class "content" editable. Whenever I click the button, however, it only makes the first div editable. Is there a way to make it apply to all divs with the class "content"?

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('content')) {
        document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('content');
  }
}

let editBtn = document.querySelector('#edit_content');
let content = document.querySelector('.content');

editBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    content.contentEditable = !content.isContentEditable;
  if(content.contentEditable === 'false') {
    localStorage.setItem('content', content.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

I tried using querySelectorAll(), but that just made the button not work at all.

Comment: `querySelector` only returns the first element, and IDs can legally only be associated with a single element. If you want multiple elements to share some "grouping identifier", you want `class`es instead. And then you'd use `querySelectorAll`, and loop over the elements.

Comment: @Krampus When I used querySelectorAll, all I did was change querySelector to querySelectorAll in the code above.

Comment: That won't work because `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an element, it returns a sequence of elements, and you can't call `addaddEventListener` on that sequence.